# Basic rendering - onDraw() method question

Tags: android

I am declaring a class that extends activity and an inner class that extends view and contains the onDraw() method, which also contains the invalidate() method. In my overriden onCreate() method I instantiate the outer class. My question is how the onDraw() method is called, since I never call it manually.

PS: I understand this might be a simple java language trick - I admit I am not the best here!

Comment: View will draw itself automatically calling onDraw() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you call `invalidate()` on a view, it tells the Android OS to redraw it.  Then it will call the `onDraw()` method. Since you put the `invalidate()` call inside the `onDraw()` method, you're basically telling the OS to constantly redraw the view.  It's a handy way to do custom animations.

Comment: thanks for your response but I already know that, what I don't know is how we get into the onDraw() method (just say there is no invalidate() and it only gets rendered once)

Comment: The view starts out pre-invalidated when it first becomes visible to the user.  Thus, onDraw() is always called at least once on all visible views and is beyond your control.

Comment: so shall I assume that since onDraw is always called, if I create another method, that method will be called aswell (since it extends view)?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The OS will not call your custom methods automatically.  You have to call them in the onDraw() method if you want that to happen.  Some views do have Android specific methods that the OS will call.  For example, SurfaceViews have onSurfaceCreated which is called automatically once when the view is created and onSurfaceChange which is called automatically when the view size changes (like an orientation switch).  Your, personal methods, will not be called and have to be called manually.